# Add object to an array in yaml via Kustomize

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, kustomize

how can I add object to array via Kustomize? As a result I would like to have two `ServiceAccount`s added to `subjects`, like so:

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: binding
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: system:auth-delegator
subjects:
  - kind: ServiceAccount
    name: name
    namespace: test1
  - kind: ServiceAccount
    name: name
    namespace: test2
```

I'm trying with that patch:

```
- op: add
  path: "/subjects/0"
  value:
    kind: ServiceAccount
    name: name
    namespace: test1
```

And another patch for second environment:

```
- op: add
  path: "/subjects/1"
  value:
    kind: ServiceAccount
    name: name
    namespace: test2
```

But in result I'm getting duplicated `subjects`, so of course it is wrong:

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: binding
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: system:auth-delegator
subjects:
  - kind: ServiceAccount
    name: name
    namespace: test1 // the same...
  - kind: ServiceAccount
    name: name
    namespace: test1 // ...as here
```

What would be a proper way to add it?

Comment: I'm unclear if the first example represents what the resource looks like *before* patching, or if that's what you want it to look like. What does the resource look like before patching? What do you expect the resource to look like when you're done?

Comment: Hi, thank you for responding. First example is what I'm expecting to have. I've also updated the question.

Answer (score 6):

If I start with a ClusterRoleBinding that looks like this in `crb.yaml`:

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: binding
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: system:auth-delegator
subjects: []
```

And I create a `kustomization.yaml` file like this:

```
apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Kustomization

resources:
  - crb.yaml

patches:
  - target:
      kind: ClusterRoleBinding
      name: binding
    patch: |
      - op: add
        path: /subjects/0
        value:
          kind: ServiceAccount
          name: name
          namespace: test1

  - target:
      kind: ClusterRoleBinding
      name: binding
    patch: |
      - op: add
        path: /subjects/1
        value:
          kind: ServiceAccount
          name: name
          namespace: test2
```

Then I get as output:

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: binding
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: system:auth-delegator
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: name
  namespace: test1
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: name
  namespace: test2
```

Which is I think what you're looking for. Does this help? Note that instead of explicitly setting an index in the `path`, like:

```
path: /subjects/0
```

We can instead specify:

```
path: /subjects/-
```

Which means "append to the list", and in this case will generate the same output.

Comment: When I run `kustomize` command with the first patch (for test1) and then the second one (test2) instead of this being added it is replaced.

Comment: Those two patched in my setup are in the different pipelines so they are applied separately.

Comment: Or maybe actually it cannot be done only with kustomize? I mean first it would need to check what is actual state of k8s object inside the cluster and then modify it.

Comment: Kustomize doesn't know about the state of resources in the clusters; it's just a tool for patching YAML.

Comment: Thank you for the note near the end, on using `-` for index to append. That was the clincher for me!